# generate alphanumeric string from pattern

Tags: shell-script

I want to generate host names for example from my patter like this: `inc-[tnc][app|web][1-10]` where it should output like below:

```
inc-tapp1
inc-tapp2
.
.
inc-tapp10
inc-napp1
.
.
inc-capp10
inc-tweb1
.
.
inc-cweb10
```

Here t,n,c represents our datacenters in texas, new york and california.

Comment: You want to expand that out to a list of all possible values?

Answer (score 1):

Just use bash expansion.

```
$ echo inc-{t,n,c}{app,web}{1..10}
inc-tapp1 inc-tapp2 inc-tapp3 inc-tapp4 inc-tapp5 inc-tapp6 inc-tapp7 inc-tapp8 inc-tapp9 inc-tapp10 inc-tweb1 inc-tweb2 inc-tweb3 inc-tweb4 inc-tweb5 inc-tweb6 inc-tweb7 inc-tweb8 inc-tweb9 inc-tweb10 inc-napp1 inc-napp2 inc-napp3 inc-napp4 inc-napp5 inc-napp6 inc-napp7 inc-napp8 inc-napp9 inc-napp10 inc-nweb1 inc-nweb2 inc-nweb3 inc-nweb4 inc-nweb5 inc-nweb6 inc-nweb7 inc-nweb8 inc-nweb9 inc-nweb10 inc-capp1 inc-capp2 inc-capp3 inc-capp4 inc-capp5 inc-capp6 inc-capp7 inc-capp8 inc-capp9 inc-capp10 inc-cweb1 inc-cweb2 inc-cweb3 inc-cweb4 inc-cweb5 inc-cweb6 inc-cweb7 inc-cweb8 inc-cweb9 inc-cweb10
$
```

Or if you want a line break between each, pipe through tr.

```
$ echo inc-{t,n,c}{app,web}{1..10}|tr " " "\n"
inc-tapp1
inc-tapp2
inc-tapp3
[etc]
```

Comment: No need to pipe to `tr`:  `printf %s\\n inc-{t,n,c}{app,web}{1..10}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell brace expansion

```
bash$ echo a{d,c,b}e
ade ace abe
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion